# Cómo comparar dos tablas

Tags: python, numpy

soy nueva en el mundo de la programación y quisiera saber como puedo comparar los valores de dos tablas.
Estoy realizando un estudio respecto a la incidencia delictiva de 2015 a 2019, y quiero proyectar la diferencia entre los años (2015 y 2016, 2016 y 2017, 2017 y 2018, 2018 y 2019) proyectando el incremento o decremento según sea el caso.

Cada tabla cuenta con la incidencia total por mes:

```
Enero   Febrero Marzo   Abril   Mayo    Junio   Julio   Agosto  Septiembre  Octubre Noviembre   Diciembre
239796  242252  261146  255252  262938  264654  259006  258726  261280       269740  257094     241082
```

Se me había ocurrido realizarlo mediante mediante una función, de esta manera:

```
def dif (2015,2016):
 if len(2015) > len(2016
 return  2016-2015
 else len(2015) < len(2016)
 return 2015-2016
```

No sé si haya alguna otra manera de realizarlo

Comment: Para este tipo de análisis es muy cómodo usar `pandas`. El código que suministras no está bien. Para empezar `2015` o `2016` no pueden ser nombres de variables ni de parámetros, pero digamos que se llaman por ejemplo `data2015` y `data2016` respectivamente. En ese caso podrías retornar simplemente la diferencia como has hecho, si ambas variables son arrays numpy o dataframes de pandas, pero no si son listas python. Por otro lado no veo la necesidad de comparar antes sus `len()`. Esta función te da cuántos elementos hay en el array y se supone que serán iguales (12 elementos).

Comment: Además el código no está correctamente indentado, le falta cerrar paréntesis, le faltan los dos puntos tras las condiciones... pero eso son detalles de sintaxis. Lo importante es la idea y creo que la idea sería simplemente calcular `data2016-data2015`

Comment: Muchas gracias. No estaba segura si el código estaba bien, pero que bueno que entendiste mi idea. Lo voy a intentar de esa manera. 
Gracias